# Do functions clear dynamic memory upon exiting scope?

Tags: c++, function, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

In C++, how does a function treat memory that has been dynamically allocated upon exiting the scope of the function? Is this memory cleared, or can it be passed back into the main block?

In context: I have a function, and I pass it a pointer to double to serve as an array. I dynamically allocate this memory within the function, initialise the elements and the exit the function.

```
            void my_func(double* ptr){
            ptr = new double[2];
            ptr[0] = 15; ptr[1] = 10;
            }
```

In the main block, I then use the newly allocated array.

```
            int main(){
            double* ptr;
            my_func(ptr);
            cout << ptr[0] + ptr[1] << endl;
            delete[] ptr;
            return 0;
```

Will this work? Are there dangers/pitfalls associated with this approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In C++, how does a function treat memory that has been dynamically allocated upon exiting the scope of the function? Is this memory cleared, or can it be passed back into the main block?

In C++, memory that has been manually (dynamically) allocated has to be manually deallocated.

> In context: I have a function, and I pass it a pointer to double to serve as an array. I dynamically allocate this memory within the function, initialise the elements and the exit the function.

You are taking the pointer by value, so while you can change the contents of what the pointer points to you cannot change the pointer itself. Doing so changes only the local copy of the pointer. If you take the pointer by reference, then it would work:

```
void my_func(double*& ptr)
{
    ptr = new double[2];
    ptr[0] = 15; ptr[1] = 10;
}
```

> Will this work? Are there dangers/pitfalls associated with this approach?

It will mostly work, but its not the way to go in C++ because of the associated pitfalls. Better go with a `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> my_func()
{
    std::vector<int> buffer;
    buffer.push_back(15);
    buffer.push_back(10);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: `so while you can change(as defined by the standards) the contents of what the pointer points to` -  is true only when the pointer is already allocated some memory. In this case `ptr = new double[2]`  will make the pointer `ptr` point to legally allocateted memory and by this step, the bearing of ptr(in the main) to the ptr(in the function) ends.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work? Are there dangers/pitfalls associated with this approach?

It may work as long as nothing goes wrong. If an exception gets thrown, it'll generally leak memory. To avoid that, you generally want to free the memory in the destructor of some class, then create an instance of that class with automatic storage duration. That means it'll be destroyed when it goes out of scope, and will (in turn) release the memory it's controlling.

The standard library already has a variety of containers to do that. What you have is closest to a `std::vector`, but there are also `std::deque`, `std::list` etc.